# SELECT times out from program but works from SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am getting a timeout when executing an SQL SELECT.

I connect to the database thus:

```
using (SQLConnection conn = SQLConnection(@"Data Source=mydbServer;Initial Catalog=mydb;Integrated Security=true;Timeout=180");
{
    conn.Open();
```

and that successfully connects.

Inside the using{} I set:

```
string query = @"SELECT a.field, a.timestamp " +
               "FROM mydb.dbo.myTable1 a WITH(NOLOCK) " +
               "LEFT JOIN [myOtherdbServer].myOtherdb.dbo.MyTable2 b WITH(NOLOCK) " +
               "ON a.field = b.field " +
               "WHERE b.field is NULL " +
               "AND a.timestamp >= '2015-05-01 00:00:00.000' " +
               "AND a.timestamp < '2015-06-01 00:00.00.000'";
```

and execute the command thus:

```
using (SQLCommand queryCmd = new SQLCommand(query, conn)
{
    queryCmd.CommandTimeout = 300;

    using (SQLDataReader rdr = queryCmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
```

The SQLCommand throws a timeout exception: "The timeout period elapsed prior to the completion of the operation or the server is not responding".

If I use SQL Server Management Studio on the same system my program is running on, and as the same user under which my program is running, and execute the same SELECT, it completes in under 1 second and returns several thousand rows.

This is happening consistently now.  It was working a couple of days ago.  What should I be looking for?  I'm baffled because the same SELECT works from SQL Server Management Studio.  Does SQL SMS use a different connection?

Comment: it is because result set is big and query is taking more time than the default timeout so it timeouts\

Comment: better is use paging and dont fetch all records in one go

Comment: The same query in SQL Server Management Studio completes in 1 second.  I can't believe that takes more than 5 minutes programmatically.

Comment: Have you tried creating a debugging point where it creates the query... then using the textviewer to copy that query into SSMS?

Comment: There's still a typo - on the line...

"LEFT JOIN [myOtherdbServer].myOtherdb.dbo.MyTable2 b " + WITH(NOLOCK) " +

...the quotes are unbalanced.  This is even picked up by this site's built in code syntax coloring.

Comment: @DiscipleMichael Yes, that's how I tested the query in SSMS and determined it took only a second ir two to complete

Comment: Are you writing your code/debugging on the same device you are running SSMS?  If not, have you eliminated connection issues to your DB?

Comment: Also, where are you actually executing the command?  Sounds silly, but you are actually running an execute method and filling some type of data object, right.... Don't be offended, just asking.

Comment: @DiscipleMichael Yes, as stated in the question, running my code and SMSS on the same system.  As to the execute method - yes, I call ExecuteReader() I will edit the question to reflect that

Comment: How about maybe Windows (or any other) software firewall getting in the way? Maybe the SSMS app has an exception defined that allows the connection to the DB server, but VS and/or your compiled C# app does not?

Comment: @LDMJoe That's possible I suppose - I'll look into it.  Thanks.

Comment: I noticed you are connecting to a second server on the joining table.  This might be causing your problem if your query is waiting for a connection to the other server.    Can you rework the query to eliminate the join with the other server and see if it runs quickly.    Just a thought

Comment: The comment of Sparky has a very good point, connecting to a remote server is very expensive. If it runs well in management studio, check in your code if you are closing your connections. You can be running in a problem of connection pool and no available connection. In the connection time out add a cero, this is infinite time or until the server say ok throw an error.

Comment: There might be a bunch of things you can try:

1. Try using profiler while running the query from the code & query from the SSMS and check the difference, may be there is some problem in how your query is being parsed.
2. Try to use Execution plan to see if any improvements are required.
3. Try for indexes if required to make the query run faster.

Answer (score 4):

***"If I use SQL Server Management Studio on the same system my program is running on, and as the same user under which my program is running, and execute the same SELECT, it completes in under 1 second and returns several thousand rows."***

1. There can be several reasons to why the execution time in SQL server management studio is better. For once, results are [Cached](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2002576/sql-server-cache-question), it may also very well be that you are lacking indexes on the timestamp column
2. In addition, is your application server located on the same server as you sql server? If not, this may increase latency and cause timeouts.
3. Linked servers may be an issue, except for latency considerations, I'm not sure the NOLOCK statement is sufficient to ensure what youre trying to achieve on the remote server. There's a good chance you may need to create a view on the remote server that contains the NOLOCK statement.

***This is happening consistently now. It was working a couple of days ago. What should I be looking for? I'm baffled because the same SELECT works from SQL Server Management Studio. Does SQL SMS use a different connection?***

Usually when something was working and now it has stopped working, then something was changed. Start troubleshooting until you find what it is, look for index changes, code architecture modifications, even windows updates, anything which may give you a lead, until you are able to restore it.

Additional advice,
try limiting the select statement to TOP 10, just to see you are able to get back results, this may indicate the issue is in the object's size / query execution time, and not with your server / application configuration.